# Camera2 API is not working in android Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am using camera 2 API to use custom camera in my app, it works fine on every device but not working on Marshmallow.
In marshmallow it opens only once, then everytime it shows black screen.

> This is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sitetrack"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
    }
    // useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}


dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0-rc03'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1"
    //Picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    //Design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    //Dimensions
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    //Library
    implementation project(':loaderLibrary')
    //Multidex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //GoogleServices
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    //Custom Camera
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.0-alpha08"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-alpha08"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-alpha08"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha05"
    //AWS
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-rekognition:2.16.4'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.16.4'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.16.4'
    implementation 'me.aflak.libraries:ezcam:2.3.3'
    //Crashlytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0-beta01'
    //FCM
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0'
    // Navigation library
    def nav_version = "2.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

> This is camera class where I am using camera api for clicking picture
>   and then sending it to next screen and saving it in device

```
  package com.sitetrack.Ui.Camera.fragments

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.DisplayMetrics
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap
import android.widget.ImageButton
import androidx.camera.core.AspectRatio
import androidx.camera.core.Camera
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.Metadata
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import com.sitetrack.R
import com.sitetrack.Ui.Camera.CameraScreen
import com.sitetrack.Util.ANIMATION_FAST_MILLIS
import com.sitetrack.Util.ANIMATION_SLOW_MILLIS
import com.sitetrack.Ui.Camera.PreviewActivity
import com.sitetrack.Util.CommonMethods
import com.sitetrack.Util.CommonMethods.Companion.compressImage
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.camera_ui_container.*
import java.io.File
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.ArrayDeque
import java.util.Locale
import java.util.concurrent.Executor
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import kotlin.math.abs
import kotlin.math.max
import kotlin.math.min

/** Helper type alias used for analysis use case callbacks */
typealias LumaListener = (luma: Double) -> Unit

/**
 * Main fragment for this app. Implements all camera operations including:
 * - Viewfinder
 * - Photo taking
 * - Image analysis
 */
class CameraFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var container: ConstraintLayout
    private lateinit var viewFinder: PreviewView
    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
    private lateinit var broadcastManager: LocalBroadcastManager
    private lateinit var displayManager: DisplayManager
    private lateinit var mainExecutor: Executor
    private lateinit var analysisExecutor: Executor

    private var displayId: Int = -1
    private var lensFacing: Int = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
    private var preview: Preview? = null
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private var imageAnalyzer: ImageAnalysis? = null
    private var camera: Camera? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mainExecutor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext())
        analysisExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        // Make sure that all permissions are still present, since the
        // user could have removed them while the app was in paused state.
        if (!PermissionsFragment.hasPermissions(
                requireContext())) {
            Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container).navigate(
                CameraFragmentDirections.actionCameraToPermissions()
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false)

    private fun setGalleryThumbnail(file: File) {
        startActivity(Intent(activity, PreviewActivity::class.java)
            .putExtra("actualImage",file.absolutePath))
        activity!!.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left)
        activity!!.finish()

    }

    /** Define callback that will be triggered after a photo has been taken and saved to disk */
    private val imageSavedListener = object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
        override fun onError(imageCaptureError: Int, message: String, cause: Throwable?) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: $message", cause)
        }

        override fun onImageSaved(photoFile: File) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Photo capture succeeded: ${photoFile.absolutePath}")

            // We can only change the foreground Drawable using API level 23+ API
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                // Update the gallery thumbnail with latest picture taken
                setGalleryThumbnail(photoFile)
            }

            // Implicit broadcasts will be ignored for devices running API level >= 24
            // so if you only target API level 24+ you can remove this statement
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                requireActivity().sendBroadcast(
                        Intent(android.hardware.Camera.ACTION_NEW_PICTURE, Uri.fromFile(photoFile))
                )
            }

            // If the folder selected is an external media directory, this is unnecessary
            // but otherwise other apps will not be able to access our images unless we
            // scan them using [MediaScannerConnection]
            val mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(photoFile.extension)
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
                    context, arrayOf(photoFile.absolutePath), arrayOf(mimeType), null
            )
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        container = view as ConstraintLayout
        viewFinder = container.findViewById(R.id.view_finder)
        broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(view.context)

        // Determine the output directory
        outputDirectory = CameraScreen.getOutputDirectory(requireContext())

        // Wait for the views to be properly laid out
        Thread(Runnable {
            viewFinder.post {

            // Keep track of the display in which this view is attached
            displayId = viewFinder.display.displayId

            // Build UI controls
            updateCameraUi()

            // Bind use cases
            bindCameraUseCases()

        } }).start()

    }

    /**
     * Inflate camera controls and update the UI manually upon config changes to avoid removing
     * and re-adding the view finder from the view hierarchy; this provides a seamless rotation
     * transition on devices that support it.
     *
     * NOTE: The flag is supported starting in Android 8 but there still is a small flash on the
     * screen for devices that run Android 9 or below.
     */
    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        updateCameraUi()
    }

    /** Declare and bind preview, capture and analysis use cases */
    private fun bindCameraUseCases() {

        // Get screen metrics used to setup camera for full screen resolution
        val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { viewFinder.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
        Log.d(TAG, "Screen metrics: ${metrics.widthPixels} x ${metrics.heightPixels}")

        val screenAspectRatio = aspectRatio(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)

        val rotation = viewFinder.display.rotation

        // Bind the CameraProvider to the LifeCycleOwner
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(lensFacing).build()
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {

            // CameraProvider
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            preview = Preview.Builder()
                // We request aspect ratio but no resolution
                .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
                // Set initial target rotation
                .setTargetRotation(rotation)
                .build()

            // Default PreviewSurfaceProvider
            preview?.previewSurfaceProvider = viewFinder.previewSurfaceProvider

            // ImageCapture
            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                // We request aspect ratio but no resolution to match preview config, but letting
                // CameraX optimize for whatever specific resolution best fits requested capture mode
                .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
                // Set initial target rotation, we will have to call this again if rotation changes
                // during the lifecycle of this use case
                .setTargetRotation(rotation)
                .build()

            // ImageAnalysis
            imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                // We request aspect ratio but no resolution
                .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
                // Set initial target rotation, we will have to call this again if rotation changes
                // during the lifecycle of this use case
                .setTargetRotation(rotation)
                .build()
                // The analyzer can then be assigned to the instance
                .also {
                    it.setAnalyzer(analysisExecutor,
                        LuminosityAnalyzer { luma ->
                            // Values returned from our analyzer are passed to the attached listener
                            // We log image analysis results here - you should do something useful instead!
                            Log.d(
                                TAG, "Average luminosity: $luma"
                            )
                        })
                }

            // Must unbind the use-cases before rebinding them.
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()

            try {
                // A variable number of use-cases can be passed here -
                // camera provides access to CameraControl & CameraInfo
                camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this as LifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalyzer
                )
            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, mainExecutor)
    }

    /**
     *  [androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysisConfig] requires enum value of
     *  [androidx.camera.core.AspectRatio]. Currently it has values of 4:3 & 16:9.
     *
     *  Detecting the most suitable ratio for dimensions provided in @params by counting absolute
     *  of preview ratio to one of the provided values.
     *
     *  @param width - preview width
     *  @param height - preview height
     *  @return suitable aspect ratio
     */
    private fun aspectRatio(width: Int, height: Int): Int {
        val previewRatio = max(width, height).toDouble() / min(width, height)
        if (abs(previewRatio - RATIO_4_3_VALUE) <= abs(previewRatio - RATIO_16_9_VALUE)) {
            return AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3
        }
        return AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9
    }

    /** Method used to re-draw the camera UI controls, called every time configuration changes. */
    private fun updateCameraUi() {

        // Remove previous UI if any
        container.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.camera_ui_container)?.let {
            container.removeView(it)
        }

        // Inflate a new view containing all UI for controlling the camera
        val controls = View.inflate(requireContext(), R.layout.camera_ui_container, container)

        // Listener for button used to capture photo
        controls.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.camera_capture_button).setOnClickListener {
                camera_capture_button.isEnabled = false
            // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
            imageCapture?.let { imageCapture ->

                // Create output file to hold the image
                val photoFile =
                    createFile(outputDirectory, FILENAME, PHOTO_EXTENSION
                    )

                // Setup image capture metadata
                val metadata = Metadata().apply {

                    // Mirror image when using the front camera
                    isReversedHorizontal = lensFacing == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
                }

                // Setup image capture listener which is triggered after photo has been taken
                imageCapture.takePicture(photoFile, metadata, mainExecutor, imageSavedListener)

                // We can only change the foreground Drawable using API level 23+ API
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                    // Display flash animation to indicate that photo was captured
                    container.postDelayed({
                        container.foreground = ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE)
                        container.postDelayed(
                                { container.foreground = null },
                            ANIMATION_FAST_MILLIS
                        )
                    }, ANIMATION_SLOW_MILLIS)
                }
            }
        }

        // Listener for button used to switch cameras
        controls.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.camera_switch_button).setOnClickListener {
            lensFacing = if (CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT == lensFacing) {
                CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK
            } else {
                CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
            }
            // Bind use cases
            bindCameraUseCases()
        }

        // Listener for button used to view the most recent photo
        controls.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.close_button).setOnClickListener {
            activity!!.finish()
        }
    }


    /**
     * Our custom image analysis class.
     *
     * <p>All we need to do is override the function `analyze` with our desired operations. Here,
     * we compute the average luminosity of the image by looking at the Y plane of the YUV frame.
     */
    private class LuminosityAnalyzer(listener: LumaListener? = null) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
        private val frameRateWindow = 8
        private val frameTimestamps = ArrayDeque<Long>(5)
        private val listeners = ArrayList<LumaListener>().apply { listener?.let { add(it) } }
        private var lastAnalyzedTimestamp = 0L
        var framesPerSecond: Double = -1.0
            private set

        /**
         * Used to add listeners that will be called with each luma computed
         */
        fun onFrameAnalyzed(listener: LumaListener) = listeners.add(listener)

        /**
         * Helper extension function used to extract a byte array from an image plane buffer
         */
        private fun ByteBuffer.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
            rewind()    // Rewind the buffer to zero
            val data = ByteArray(remaining())
            get(data)   // Copy the buffer into a byte array
            return data // Return the byte array
        }

        /**
         * Analyzes an image to produce a result.
         *
         * <p>The caller is responsible for ensuring this analysis method can be executed quickly
         * enough to prevent stalls in the image acquisition pipeline. Otherwise, newly available
         * images will not be acquired and analyzed.
         *
         * <p>The image passed to this method becomes invalid after this method returns. The caller
         * should not store external references to this image, as these references will become
         * invalid.
         *
         * @param image image being analyzed VERY IMPORTANT: Analyzer method implementation must
         * call image.close() on received images when finished using them. Otherwise, new images
         * may not be received or the camera may stall, depending on back pressure setting.
         *
         */
        override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
            // If there are no listeners attached, we don't need to perform analysis
            if (listeners.isEmpty()) {
                image.close()
                return
            }

            // Keep track of frames analyzed
            val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            frameTimestamps.push(currentTime)

            // Compute the FPS using a moving average
            while (frameTimestamps.size >= frameRateWindow) frameTimestamps.removeLast()
            val timestampFirst = frameTimestamps.peekFirst() ?: currentTime
            val timestampLast = frameTimestamps.peekLast() ?: currentTime
            framesPerSecond = 1.0 / ((timestampFirst - timestampLast) /
                    frameTimestamps.size.coerceAtLeast(1).toDouble()) * 1000.0

            // Analysis could take an arbitrarily long amount of time
            // Since we are running in a different thread, it won't stall other use cases

            lastAnalyzedTimestamp = frameTimestamps.first

            // Since format in ImageAnalysis is YUV, image.planes[0] contains the luminance plane
            val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer

            // Extract image data from callback object
            val data = buffer.toByteArray()

            // Convert the data into an array of pixel values ranging 0-255
            val pixels = data.map { it.toInt() and 0xFF }

            // Compute average luminance for the image
            val luma = pixels.average()

            // Call all listeners with new value
            listeners.forEach { it(luma) }

            image.close()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXBasic"
        private const val FILENAME = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private const val PHOTO_EXTENSION = ".jpg"
        private const val RATIO_4_3_VALUE = 4.0 / 3.0
        private const val RATIO_16_9_VALUE = 16.0 / 9.0

        /** Helper function used to create a timestamped file */
        private fun createFile(baseFolder: File, format: String, extension: String) =
                File(baseFolder, SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US)
                        .format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + extension)
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can get the logcat and filter it by "camera".

Comment: there are no logs when screen is black

Comment: I've had simular problem, Helped replacing PermissionsFragment with receiving camera permission in CameraFragment.

Comment: It fixed you problem?

Comment: @Xi张熹 what a coincidence seeing your comment here haha

Comment: @Suisse I work on CameraX. You will probably see me a lot under the android-camerax tag. :)